# Power apps fail to search multiple columns with excel data source

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am working on search the key words in multiple columns in Gallery with excel files as the data source (connected by business onedrive) in a canvas app.

When I search the key word in one single column, it works and can show the result.
however when I search the key word in 2 columns, it doesn't work and no result comes out.
My data source include the key word in the 2 columns above.
The search formula is as below:

```
Search(
    MyTableName,
    SearchInput.Text,
    "内容",
    "方案"
)
```

I use the Power App's  Monitor system and check the captured request and response. The failure is:

> Error when trying to retrieve data from the network: Invalid filter clause: unsupported operation. Only single 'eq', 'ne', 'contains', 'startswith' or 'endswith' is currently supported.
> "Invalid filter clause: unsupported operation. Only single 'eq', 'ne', 'contains', 'startswith' or 'endswith' is currently supported."

I then decode the URL and it shows as following format:

```
/apim/excelonlinebusiness/shared-excelonlinebu-1111101704-xxxxx-xx-839c-xxxxxx/v2/datasets/me,b%21uEgyxxxxxxngxjQr7ZAX3OTIa4LB65450Z,01GARUxxxBxxxxxJ3RVSZI6HRUMI/tables/{xx-1371-xx-xxxx-xxxxx}/items?$filter=(contains(方案,'q'))or(contains(内容,'q'))&pkColumn=__PowerAppsId__&isGeneratedColumn=true&$top=100
```

I see the decoded URL use filter and contains, and I'm not sure whether this is the cause...
So How Can I implement search non-English key words in multiple columns?

Comment: I did a similar thing to this but I used Office script. I used Regex to search for the work in the whole file and return the filtered result. (Running + Creating script will require Office 365 E3 Licence)